# Quickbooks Connection Error - Node

Tags: node.js, soap, quickbooks

I've been trying to find a solution to this issue for over a week with no luck, I've been trying different things from all over the boards but nothing worked so far.

I have a node / soap server trying to connect to quickbooks through the web connector, I got it to a point where if I run in my host machine and connect to it via ip from the guest (where QB / QBWC are installed), it works, but if I put it somewhere else on the network, it doesn't, it can connect and handshake, but then gives the following:

```
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'New API - Live' has STARTED
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: New API - Live
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): New API - Live
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://10.192.2.48:8000/wsdl
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:<serverVersionRet="0.2.1">
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.1.0.30">
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:<clientVersionRet="">
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'New API - Live', username = 'username'
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="username"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Received from authenticate() following parameters:<authRet[0]="013eb730-07f8-11e6-87fa-ede5c5dc6f00"><authRet[1]="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Sample Company Files\QuickBooks 2014\sample_wholesale-distribution business.qbw"><authRet[2]=""><authRet[3]="">
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceName() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceName has been set to New API - Live
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceSessionTicket() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceSessionTicket has been set to 013eb730-07f8-11e6-87fa-ede5c5dc6f00
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.CheckCFNResponse() : User authenticated.
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Done.
20160421.19:34:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20160421.19:34:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.handleAllOtherError() : QBWC1013: Error connecting to QuickBooks. Returning error message to application.
Could not start QuickBooks.
20160421.19:34:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : *** Calling connectionError() with following parameters:<wcTicket="013eb730-07f8-11e6-87fa-ede5c5dc6f00"><hresult="0x80040408"><message="Could not start QuickBooks.">
20160421.19:34:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : Received from connectionError() following parameters:<tryAgain="DONE">
20160421.19:34:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Application sent back DONE. Job ending.
20160421.19:34:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20160421.19:34:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20160421.19:34:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

Currently I'm testing it with quickbooks open and an empty string in the response (which tells QB to use the open file).

I tried entering a manual path as well, same results pretty much.

I'm using a slightly modified version of [QBWS](https://github.com/johnballantyne/qbws).

Please advise, ANY help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently I'm testing it with quickbooks open and an empty string in the response (which tells QB to use the open file).

No, you're not.

You're SOAP web service is returning this (as shown in the log you pasted):

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Sample Company Files\QuickBooks 2014\sample_wholesale-distribution business.qbw

If you hit `F2` on your keyboard, while in QuickBooks, on the same computer that the Web Connector is running on, is that the EXACT path that QuickBooks tell you the file is located at?

Comment: I did changed that locally, but didn't notice it in the log once I ran remote. As it turns out, when I was doing npm install on the remote it was overriting the changes I made and resetting the whole mod. Thanks.